# about use talib with gpu or tpu make the Calculation EMA and other faster

Tags: python, gpu, ta-lib, tpu

so i'm doing a  project with ta-lib for python , i need to Calculation EMA and other target. the data is 
10 years history data and timely stock data total is 1703 when i need to calculation EMA just for 200 stocks it spend about 19S~30S it to slow  because the timely stock is renew for 5s e and i want it calculation for 10s maybe more faster  , i think if i can use the gpu or tpu it will be fast then just use cpu so my questions is is ta-lib can use gpu or tpu ??? and how to ues that? if cant  is there anyway to make it fast? for 1703 stocks?  thanks for answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

TA-Lib doesn't support GPU or TPU. You may fork it and add GPU support to [EMA implementation](https://sourceforge.net/p/ta-lib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ta-lib/c/src/ta_func/ta_EMA.c#l347) in it. Rebuild and spoof original library with patched library.
Or you can just implement EMA calculation with GPU (the code is simple) in own lib and use it instead of TA-Lib.

Btw, I have my own fork of TA-Lib that can be paused and continued from saved state. But it looks like it won't be helpful in your case and lacks python bindings.